# What is a pushed dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to configure my VPN network settings and want to know what Pushed DNS means. By default under (Nameservers - when VPN is connected) Pushed DNS is set. I know it's good to know all the different types of DNS server connections, but it's hard to find clear explanation of all these types online. You'd think that an online search would bring up sites with clear and thorough explanations, but that is not the case.

If someone could explain Pushed DNS and send me a link to a site that explains all the different DNS connections, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

A VPN server can be configured to send (push) various parameters to a client. One of these parameters is the DNS server address that the client should use. Your client appears to be configured to accept this information and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Have you heard of a Ad Blocking DNS? Someone recommended this to me to avoid malicious websites if I wanted to mitigate getting malware from websites.

Comment: Ad blocking DNS is a DNS server that is configured to block certain bad domains.  It is one way of limiting your exposure, but not a silver bullet and is quite course - if someone uploads accessible malware on an otherwise good domain it won't be picked up.